# How many integers between 1 and 1000 inclusive that are not divisible by 3, 5 or 7?

Tags: python

I am using Python and can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code here?

```
def notdivisible():

    count =0
    for i in range(1,1001):

        while i%3 !=0 or i%5 !=0 or i%7 !=0:
            count+=1
            i+=1

    print (count)


notdivisible()
```

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what was going wrong. Errors, bad output, etc

Comment: He is most likely skipping number because he is incrementing `i` and so is the `for` loop

Answer (score 6):

```
count = 0
for i in range(1,1001):
    if i%3 and i%5 and i%7:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

You don't need a while loop, the `for` takes care of incrementing i.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: do you mean that OP asks about integers not divisible by ANY of 3, 5 or 7 (as in [dugres' code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21915377/4279))? Note: Hugh's code counts integers not divisible by ALL: 3 and 5 and 7

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: read the headline again? That is in fact the question which was asked!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: _no, no, no!_ It counts all numbers not divisible by ANY OF 3, 5, or 7 (i NOT divisible by 3 AND i NOT divisible by 5 AND i NOT divisible by 7).

Comment: I meant: ANY: `sum(any(i % k for k in [3, 5, 7]) for i in range(1, 1000+1))` , ALL: `sum(all(i % k for k in [3, 5, 7]) for i in range(1, 1000+1))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(1 for i in range(1, 1001) if i%3 and i%5 and i%7)
```

EDIT:
I'm not sure what the question actually is ; you could use "or" or "and" as needed ...

Comment: This returns the wrong answer.  I guess you meant `sum(1 for i in range(1, 1001) if i%3 * i%5 * i%7)`

Answer (score 1):

Just a different idea ...

```
>>> x = range(1001)
>>> len(set(x) - set(x[::3]) - set(x[::5]) - set(x[::7]))
457
```

p.s. the problem with your code was that line with the `while`: the `while` should have been an `if`, with each `or` changed to `and`.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop you have a `i+=1`, which is the variable that you're using in the for loop. This is causing you to skip numbers and probably why your code is not returning the expected value.

The loop variable is automatically incremented with each iteration. You don't have to update it yourself (unless that's what you actually want to do).